# Is it possible to have a library implementation of is_trivially_constructible without relying on compiler builtins?

Tags: c++, type-traits, std, libstdc++

I'm using gcc-4.9 which does not have the `is_trivially_constructible` type trait. Looking into the libstdc++ source code (type_traits), this depends on `__is_trivially_constructible` which is implemented in the compiler itself.

I was wondering if it was possible to implement this trait as a library rather than relying on compiler such that I can use this in my project which is stuck using gcc-4.9.

Comment: I don't think so. E.g. in the [llvm implementation](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/type_traits#L3447), the placeholder `is_scalar` is used which rather seems like a first approximation.

Comment: For the record, MSVC (2015) also uses an intrinsic.

Comment: @Jodocus LLVM also uses an intrinsic: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/type_traits#L3430

Comment: @Holt Yes, and in case it's not available, it will fall back on something that is actually wrong, indicating that if it was possible, the writers of libc++ would've done it.

Comment: @Jodocus, I was also looking if there is some approximate implementation. That way some of the types will benefit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not possible (otherwise we probably would have already done it in libstdc++!)

We had to wait for the new compiler builtin to be implemented.

Using `is_scalar` is a conservative approximation, but is obviously wrong for trivially constructible class types.